# Datepicker control does not fire after postpack in update panel

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have used GM's datepicker control inside update panel.Inside update panel one more control(dropdownlist) is there.Onpageload everything is working properly.After Onselectedindexchange of dropdownlist,user can select datepicker's value.It is not working.How to handle this?

```
// update panel
// datepicker
// dropdownlist
// close updatepanel
```

Comment: What is the `GM's datepicker`?

Comment: I think you need to show your markup, and probably the contents of the page load / selectedindexchanged events, in order for someone to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unbind/bind your datepicker to your TextBox every time the page (re-)loads. I don't know how your timepicker works, but with jQueryUI's you can use something like that (js):

```
function pageLoad() {
$("#myTextBox").unbind();
$("#myTextBox").datepicker();
}
```

Your textbox should use  `ClientIDMode="Static"` for that.